# Peculiar disappearance of a question thread

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why the recent question about kernel crashes has completely disappeared. This looks very bad (in that it makes mathematica.stackexchange.com look  like a Wolfram PR site, which I am sure it  is  not).

Comment: details please... It's not [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57369/why-am-i-getting-a-kernel-crash-on-chop) or [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59871/kernel-crashes-when-plotting-z-sqrtx2-y20), is it? I can see one of your answers moved to the comment section (and rightly so). Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: It is the latter one.

Comment: The question seems to be still there. What precisely is your problem then?

Comment: @Igor, the only thing that has disappeared is your answer, but its content remains as a comment.  That action was mine. (Convert answer to comment.)  I was responding to other flags/comments about the answers to that question not being real answers.  I felt that your answer could not resolve the problem (it is neither a patch/fix nor notice of one) and was therefore better as a comment.  If you feel that I acted in error I suggest you argue your case here and let the community decide what is best.

Comment: You seem to have a different concept of what an answer should be than the usual community criteria. For example in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/193) your answer was also converted to a comment. I think it's perhaps better for you to post a more broad question proposing a discussion here on meta about that and so you'll have the opportunity to exchange views.

Comment: @Belisarius If you look me up, you will see that I am not a stranger to the stackexchange network, so I speak from experience when I say that mathematica.stackexchange.com appears to have a far more draconian view of what is suitable as an answer than either MathOverflow or MSE. In particular, converting answers with multiple upvotes (which means that people found them helpful) to comments is shocking to me.

Comment: @IgorRivin I'm not taking positions here. We could have developed some particular sense about how the site should work that can be revisited. The community is _usually_ open to suggestions and improvements, but is _always_ open to reason about the do's and don'ts.

Comment: @belisarius fair enough. In any case, this question was not about that: I really could not find the original crash question any more (though my search was triggered by the mysterious change in reputation).

Comment: Well, your *answer* "This still crashes (without an error message) in Mathematica V10.0." plus a joke about the frequency, certainly looks like a comment to me. I note that [help page here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and the [help page on math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) both seem to indicate that commentary should be relegated to the comments. The fact that it happens here more regularly probably has to do more with the fact that the moderators are overworked over there.

Comment: I believe Mr. Wizard moved it to the comment section after I commented that both it and the *accepted* answer looked like comments! :)